# Find the occurrences of a key in JSON object in Java

Tags: java, javascript, json

I want to find a key in JSON that has repeated more than certain times or not. Based on the result I have to add some other key/value pairs to another JSON object. Is there any way that I can achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you wanting to find it in Java or in Javascript?

Comment: i want to find it in Java. Thanks

Comment: Pleas Add a Code Snippet for more Details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON Simple library to parse a json object: https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

After that you can simply iterate over the objects and count their occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ... something like this:

```
public int countOccurrenceOfKey(final String jsonString, final String key) {
    int occurrenceCounter = 0;
    String[] jsonParts = jsonString.split(","); // maybe another splitter if comma appears within values
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonParts.length; i=i+2) { // step to every second index so you only check the keys. start with i = 1 to check only values
        String part = jsonParts[i];
        if(part.contains(key) {
            occurrenceCounter++;
        }
    }
    return occurrenceCounter;
}
```

Why using a JSON library could probably create problems...
If your JSON string contains the same key more than 1 time (maybe you generated it manually):

A. The JSON converter could raise an exception and abort creating the object.

B. The library could only take the first or last appearance of the key so all other values for the same key could be lost.

Depends on the library implementation and on the JSON specification.

Answer (score -1):

```
{
  "responseCode": 200,
  "responseMessage": "COMPLETE",
  "responseData": "95W_RTXszAuuwsLxp8pA56UJQhMfNSVRQ-6OWd_f5-4tvBHp9WI4UgPBfop2AWPBY7xCI0QQcb2QwKuCRhSNdzbGOHlNL_Oectcb4xeUV_-cN8mqPo5iVyqXn_QtOtpn9GxlocFyLmXsjOKQgd5W_HsrmIwwldEwKLlcAzDTy9MIVSiZ3O97YXAzVZleV_yM0V4IqEd68wK3xGamCf05d_e4W-pnc56y3MSXRpu9op3Km0IdQAXj6gqeYCXe-AoZhj_OSP4pHpRJipixFpQGxWsSK2fhvZmdoNGxQRKtZGBzgJ9blCRFmNteio9_GbhOMXL6ySnSRbtSZ_RfBsjMu2m1MKWb0YOwQyOrIjKpQ3KOnXNCc0j54nF24YRmdFMZXbPktzrU90Y3HpzuX1xAZM0oAoUOm2xiJii1CJmH9YCOq3vR_eFneBFXFrOVCz29YKOkE4hlRHLlYxwgmWh91BFney0QIF9f9lyjHLTN958murr8dm6cS4BHSqWzeCrS86QuU4j7Zpgz6_jZUP-jK9Damjph2ZYJsIw5YHG_1dXRqse1RwbPYzP5xjADqgDVZm4IJfOwSiaYsuXtmm0hBj9fCj4DTVjVptnoYcv8Z649TquOYgbs-58st_bycROo9i1erwLz_nDdjIlQKPfz64a5UA",
  "responseVersion": 3
}
```